# Sorry i'm stuck with freeraduis to LDAP

Tags: openldap, freeradius

Ok Im a little stuck with FreeRad A little lost

I think I have found the problem, I just don't understand why
so If I try to auth over the wifi to rad it looks like its not getting the password below is the debug of that

```
Ready to process requests
(0) Received Access-Request Id 149 from 192.168.200.238:49881 to 192.168.20.2:1812 length 227
(0)   User-Name = "testing"
(0)   NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.200.238
(0)   NAS-Identifier = "d221f94b63df"
(0)   Called-Station-Id = "D2-21-F9-4B-63-DF:test no join"
(0)   NAS-Port-Type = Wireless-802.11
(0)   Service-Type = Framed-User
(0)   Calling-Station-Id = "D2-5A-22-F3-F6-A1"
(0)   Connect-Info = "CONNECT 0Mbps 802.11a"
(0)   Acct-Session-Id = "08DE2818B2804F38"
(0)   Acct-Multi-Session-Id = "47EF77EBC7B5BF7A"
(0)   WLAN-Pairwise-Cipher = 1027076
(0)   WLAN-Group-Cipher = 1027076
(0)   WLAN-AKM-Suite = 1027073
(0)   Framed-MTU = 1400
(0)   EAP-Message = 0x02bd000c0174657374696e67
(0)   Message-Authenticator = 0xcef6985af177d3099edb44dbcfaba6e7
(0) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/my_server
(0)   authorize {
rlm_ldap (ldap): Reserved connection (0)
(0) ldap: EXPAND (cn=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{User-Name}})
(0) ldap:    --> (cn=testing)
(0) ldap: Performing search in "ou=users,dc=ldap,DC=alexosaurous,DC=co,DC=nz" with filter "(cn=testing)", scope "sub"
(0) ldap: Waiting for search result...
(0) ldap: User object found at DN "cn=testing,ou=users,dc=ldap,dc=alexosaurous,dc=co,dc=nz"
(0) ldap: Processing user attributes
(0) ldap: WARNING: No "known good" password added. Ensure the admin user has permission to read the password attribute
(0) ldap: WARNING: PAP authentication will *NOT* work with Active Directory (if that is what you were trying to configure)
rlm_ldap (ldap): Released connection (0)
(0)     [ldap] = ok
(0)     if ((ok || updated) && User-Password) {
(0)     if ((ok || updated) && User-Password)  -> FALSE
(0)   } # authorize = ok
(0) ERROR: No Auth-Type found: rejecting the user via Post-Auth-Type = Reject
(0) Failed to authenticate the user
(0) Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
(0) Post-Auth-Type sub-section not found.  Ignoring.
(0) Delaying response for 1.000000 seconds
Waking up in 0.3 seconds.
Waking up in 0.6 seconds.
(0) Sending delayed response
(0) Sent Access-Reject Id 149 from 192.168.20.2:1812 to 192.168.200.238:49881 length 20
Waking up in 3.9 seconds.
(0) Cleaning up request packet ID 149 with timestamp +10 due to cleanup_delay was reached
```

As you can see no password in that unless I'm missing something which maybe but when I do a radtest I get accept-accept below the debug log from doing it that way

```
radtest testing test localhost 2 testing123                                                                           root@docker-host
Sent Access-Request Id 76 from 0.0.0.0:39308 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 77
    User-Name = "testing"
    User-Password = "test"
    NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
    NAS-Port = 2
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00
    Cleartext-Password = "test"
Received Access-Accept Id 76 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:39308 length 20


Ready to process requests
q(1) Received Access-Request Id 163 from 127.0.0.1:53905 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 77
(1)   User-Name = "testing"
(1)   User-Password = "test"
(1)   NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
(1)   NAS-Port = 2
(1)   Message-Authenticator = 0xfade5a334cefa11b8d1c07ea3ca02fae
(1) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/my_server
(1)   authorize {
rlm_ldap (ldap): Reserved connection (1)
(1) ldap: EXPAND (cn=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{User-Name}})
(1) ldap:    --> (cn=testing)
(1) ldap: Performing search in "ou=users,dc=ldap,DC=alexosaurous,DC=co,DC=nz" with filter "(cn=testing)", scope "sub"
(1) ldap: Waiting for search result...
(1) ldap: User object found at DN "cn=testing,ou=users,dc=ldap,dc=alexosaurous,dc=co,dc=nz"
(1) ldap: Processing user attributes
(1) ldap: WARNING: No "known good" password added. Ensure the admin user has permission to read the password attribute
(1) ldap: WARNING: PAP authentication will *NOT* work with Active Directory (if that is what you were trying to configure)
rlm_ldap (ldap): Released connection (1)
rlm_ldap (ldap): Closing connection (2) - Too many unused connections.
rlm_ldap (ldap): You probably need to lower "min"
rlm_ldap (ldap): Closing expired connection (4) - Hit idle_timeout limit
rlm_ldap (ldap): You probably need to lower "min"
rlm_ldap (ldap): Closing expired connection (3) - Hit idle_timeout limit
(1)     [ldap] = ok
(1)     if ((ok || updated) && User-Password) {
(1)     if ((ok || updated) && User-Password)  -> TRUE
(1)     if ((ok || updated) && User-Password)  {
(1)       update {
(1)         control:Auth-Type := LDAP
(1)       } # update = noop
(1)     } # if ((ok || updated) && User-Password)  = noop
(1)   } # authorize = ok
(1) Found Auth-Type = LDAP
(1) # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/my_server
(1)   Auth-Type LDAP {
rlm_ldap (ldap): Reserved connection (0)
(1) ldap: Login attempt by "testing"
(1) ldap: Using user DN from request "cn=testing,ou=users,dc=ldap,dc=alexosaurous,dc=co,dc=nz"
(1) ldap: Waiting for bind result...
(1) ldap: Bind successful
(1) ldap: Bind as user "cn=testing,ou=users,dc=ldap,dc=alexosaurous,dc=co,dc=nz" was successful
rlm_ldap (ldap): Released connection (0)
(1)     [ldap] = ok
(1)   } # Auth-Type LDAP = ok
(1) Sent Access-Accept Id 163 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:53905 length 20
(1) Finished request
Waking up in 4.9 seconds.
(1) Cleaning up request packet ID 163 with timestamp +67 due to cleanup_delay was reached
Ready to process requests
(2) Received Access-Request Id 210 from 127.0.0.1:49536 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 77
Dropping packet without response because of error: Received packet from 127.0.0.1 with invalid Message-Authenticator!  (Shared secret is incorrect.)
Waking up in 0.3 seconds.
(2) Cleaning up request packet ID 210 with timestamp +109 due to done
Ready to process requests
```

In that request looks like it got the password and had put it in LDAP then authed the username and password

I'm so very lost as to way the phone over wifi is not sending the password

config below

sites enabled

```
server my_server {
listen {
        type = auth
        ipaddr = *
        port = 1812
}
authorize {
        ldap
        if ((ok || updated) && User-Password) {
        update {
        control:Auth-Type := ldap
          }
        }
        
}
authenticate {
        Auth-Type LDAP {
                ldap
        }
}
}
```

LDAP config

```
# -*- text -*-
#
#  $Id: 1f0ee0383834684c7314a89be40003933023c401 $

#
#  Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP)
#
ldap {
    #  Note that this needs to match the name(s) in the LDAP server
    #  certificate, if you're using ldaps.  See OpenLDAP documentation
    #  for the behavioral semantics of specifying more than one host.
    server = "auth.domain"

    #  Port to connect on, defaults to 389. Setting this to 636 will enable
    #  LDAPS if start_tls (see below) is not able to be used.
    port = "389"

    #  Administrator account for searching and possibly modifying.
    identity = "cn=myserviceaccount,dc=domain"
    password = ""

    #  Unless overridden in another section, the dn from which all
    #  searches will start from.
    base_dn = "dc=ldap,dc=alexosaurous,dc=co,dc=nz"

    #
    #  Generic valuepair attribute
    #

    #  If set, this will attribute will be retrieved in addition to any
    #  mapped attributes.
    #
    #  Values should be in the format:
    #   <radius attr> <op> <value>
    #
    #  Where:
    #   <radius attr>:  Is the attribute you wish to create
    #           with any valid list and request qualifiers.
    #   <op>:       Is any assignment attribute (=, :=, +=, -=).
    #   <value>:    Is the value to parse into the new valuepair.
    #           If the attribute name is wrapped in double
    #           quotes it will be xlat expanded.
#   valuepair_attribute = "radiusAttribute"

    #
    #  Mapping of LDAP directory attributes to RADIUS dictionary attributes.
    #

    #  WARNING: Although this format is almost identical to the unlang
    #  update section format, it does *NOT* mean that you can use other
    #  unlang constructs in module configuration files.
    #
    #  Configuration items are in the format:
    #   <radius attr> <op> <ldap attr>
    #
    #  Where:
    #   <radius attr>:  Is the destination RADIUS attribute
    #           with any valid list and request qualifiers.
    #   <op>:       Is any assignment attribute (=, :=, +=, -=).
    #   <ldap attr>:    Is the attribute associated with user or
    #           profile objects in the LDAP directory.
    #           If the attribute name is wrapped in double
    #           quotes it will be xlat expanded.
    #
    #  Request and list qualifiers may also be placed after the 'update'
    #  section name to set defaults destination requests/lists
    #  for unqualified RADIUS attributes.
    #
    #  Note: LDAP attribute names should be single quoted unless you want
    #  the name value to be derived from an xlat expansion, or an
    #  attribute ref.
    update {
        control:Password-With-Header    += 'userPassword'
#       control:NT-Password     := 'ntPassword'
#       reply:Reply-Message     := 'radiusReplyMessage'
#       reply:Tunnel-Type       := 'radiusTunnelType'
#       reply:Tunnel-Medium-Type    := 'radiusTunnelMediumType'
#       reply:Tunnel-Private-Group-ID   := 'radiusTunnelPrivategroupId'

        #  These are provided for backwards compatibility.
        #  Where only a list is specified as the RADIUS attribute,
        #  the value of the LDAP attribute is parsed as a valuepair
        #  in the same format as the 'valuepair_attribute' (above).
#       control:            += 'radiusCheckAttributes'
#       reply:              += 'radiusReplyAttributes'
    }

    #  Set to yes if you have eDirectory and want to use the universal
    #  password mechanism.
#   edir = no

    #  Set to yes if you want to bind as the user after retrieving the
    #  Cleartext-Password. This will consume the login grace, and
    #  verify user authorization.
#   edir_autz = no

    #  Note: set_auth_type was removed in v3.x.x
    #  Equivalent functionality can be achieved by adding the following
    #  stanza to the authorize {} section of your virtual server.
    #
    #    ldap
    #    if ((ok || updated) && User-Password) {
    #        update {
    #            control:Auth-Type := ldap
    #        }
    #    }

    #
    #  User object identification.
    #
    user {
        #  Where to start searching in the tree for users
        base_dn = "ou=users,dc=ldap,DC=alexosaurous,DC=co,DC=nz"

        #  Filter for user objects, should be specific enough
        #  to identify a single user object.
        filter = "(cn=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{User-Name}})"

        #  Search scope, may be 'base', 'one', sub' or 'children'
#       scope = 'sub'

        #  If this is undefined, anyone is authorised.
        #  If it is defined, the contents of this attribute
        #  determine whether or not the user is authorised
#       access_attribute = "dialupAccess"

        #  Control whether the presence of "access_attribute"
        #  allows access, or denys access.
        #
        #  If "yes", and the access_attribute is present, or
        #  "no" and the access_attribute is absent then access
        #  will be allowed.
        #
        #  If "yes", and the access_attribute is absent, or
        #  "no" and the access_attribute is present, then
        #  access will not be allowed.
        #
        #  If the value of the access_attribute is "false", it
        #  will negate the result.
        #
        #  e.g.
        #    access_positive = yes
        #    access_attribute = userAccessAllowed
        #
        #    userAccessAllowed = false
        #
        #  Will result in the user being locked out.
#       access_positive = yes
    }

    #
    #  User membership checking.
    #
    group {
        #  Where to start searching in the tree for groups
        base_dn = "ou=Groups,dc=ldap,DC=alexosaurous,DC=co,DC=nz"

        #  Filter for group objects, should match all available
        #  group objects a user might be a member of.
        filter = "(objectClass=posixGroup)"

        # Search scope, may be 'base', 'one', sub' or 'children'
#       scope = 'sub'

        #  Attribute that uniquely identifies a group.
        #  Is used when converting group DNs to group
        #  names.
        name_attribute = cn

        #  Filter to find group objects a user is a member of.
        #  That is, group objects with attributes that
        #  identify members (the inverse of membership_attribute).
        membership_filter = "(|(member=%{control:Ldap-UserDn})(memberUid=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{User-Name}}))"

        #  The attribute in user objects which contain the names
        #  or DNs of groups a user is a member of.
        #
        #  Unless a conversion between group name and group DN is
        #  needed, there's no requirement for the group objects
        #  referenced to actually exist.
#       membership_attribute = "memberOf"

        #  If cacheable_name or cacheable_dn are enabled,
        #  all group information for the user will be
        #  retrieved from the directory and written to LDAP-Group
        #  attributes appropriate for the instance of rlm_ldap.
        #
        #  For group comparisons these attributes will be checked
        #  instead of querying the LDAP directory directly.
        #
        #  This feature is intended to be used with rlm_cache.
        #
        #  If you wish to use this feature, you should enable
        #  the type that matches the format of your check items
        #  i.e. if your groups are specified as DNs then enable
        #  cacheable_dn else enable cacheable_name.
#       cacheable_name = "no"
#       cacheable_dn = "no"

        #  Override the normal cache attribute (<inst>-LDAP-Group)
        #  and create a custom attribute.  This can help if multiple
        #  module instances are used in fail-over.
#       cache_attribute = "LDAP-Cached-Membership"
    }

    #
    #  User profiles. RADIUS profile objects contain sets of attributes
    #  to insert into the request. These attributes are mapped using
    #  the same mapping scheme applied to user objects.
    #
    profile {
        #  Filter for RADIUS profile objects
#       filter = "(objectclass=radiusprofile)"

        #  The default profile applied to all users.
#       default = "cn=radprofile,dc=example,dc=org"

        #  The list of profiles which are applied (after the default)
        #  to all users.
        #  The "User-Profile" attribute in the control list
        #  will override this setting at run-time.
#       attribute = "radiusProfileDn"
    }

    #
    #  Bulk load clients from the directory
    #
    client {
        #   Where to start searching in the tree for clients
        base_dn = "ou=Clients,dc=example,dc=com"

        #
        #  Filter to match client objects
        #
        filter = '(objectClass=frClient)'

        # Search scope, may be 'base', 'one', 'sub' or 'children'
#       scope = 'sub'

        #
        #  Client attribute mappings are in the format:
        #      <client attribute> = <ldap attribute>
        #
        #  Arbitrary attributes (accessible by %{client:<attr>}) are not yet supported.
        #
        #  The following attributes are required:
        #    * identifier - IPv4 address, or IPv4 address with prefix, or hostname.
        #    * secret - RADIUS shared secret.
        #
        #  The following attributes are optional:
        #    * shortname - Friendly name associated with the client
        #    * nas_type - NAS Type
        #    * virtual_server - Virtual server to associate the client with
        #    * require_message_authenticator - Whether we require the Message-Authenticator
        #      attribute to be present in requests from the client.
        #
        #  Schemas are available in doc/schemas/ldap for openldap and eDirectory
        #
        attribute {
            identifier          = 'radiusClientIdentifier'
            secret              = 'radiusClientSecret'
#           shortname           = 'radiusClientShortname'
#           nas_type            = 'radiusClientType'
#           virtual_server          = 'radiusClientVirtualServer'
#           require_message_authenticator   = 'radiusClientRequireMa'
        }
    }

    #  Load clients on startup
#   read_clients = no

    #
    #  Modify user object on receiving Accounting-Request
    #

    #  Useful for recording things like the last time the user logged
    #  in, or the Acct-Session-ID for CoA/DM.
    #
    #  LDAP modification items are in the format:
    #   <ldap attr> <op> <value>
    #
    #  Where:
    #   <ldap attr>:    The LDAP attribute to add modify or delete.
    #   <op>:       One of the assignment operators:
    #           (:=, +=, -=, ++).
    #           Note: '=' is *not* supported.
    #   <value>:    The value to add modify or delete.
    #
    #  WARNING: If using the ':=' operator with a multi-valued LDAP
    #  attribute, all instances of the attribute will be removed and
    #  replaced with a single attribute.
    accounting {
        reference = "%{tolower:type.%{Acct-Status-Type}}"

        type {
            start {
                update {
                    description := "Online at %S"
                }
            }

            interim-update {
                update {
                    description := "Last seen at %S"
                }
            }

            stop {
                update {
                    description := "Offline at %S"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #
    #  Post-Auth can modify LDAP objects too
    #
    post-auth {
        update {
            description := "Authenticated at %S"
        }
    }

    #
    #  LDAP connection-specific options.
    #
    #  These options set timeouts, keep-alives, etc. for the connections.
    #
    options {
        #  Control under which situations aliases are followed.
        #  May be one of 'never', 'searching', 'finding' or 'always'
        #  default: libldap's default which is usually 'never'.
        #
        #  LDAP_OPT_DEREF is set to this value.
#       dereference = 'always'

        #
        #  The following two configuration items control whether the
        #  server follows references returned by LDAP directory.
        #  They are  mostly for Active Directory compatibility.
        #  If you set these to "no", then searches will likely return
        #  "operations error", instead of a useful result.
        #
        chase_referrals = yes
        rebind = yes

        #  Seconds to wait for LDAP query to finish. default: 20
        timeout = 10

        #  Seconds LDAP server has to process the query (server-side
        #  time limit). default: 20
        #
        #  LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT is set to this value.
        timelimit = 3

        #  Seconds to wait for response of the server. (network
        #  failures) default: 10
        #
        #  LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT is set to this value.
        net_timeout = 1

        #  LDAP_OPT_X_KEEPALIVE_IDLE
        idle = 60

        #  LDAP_OPT_X_KEEPALIVE_PROBES
        probes = 3

        #  LDAP_OPT_X_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL
        interval = 3

        #  ldap_debug: debug flag for LDAP SDK
        #  (see OpenLDAP documentation).  Set this to enable
        #  huge amounts of LDAP debugging on the screen.
        #  You should only use this if you are an LDAP expert.
        #
        #   default: 0x0000 (no debugging messages)
        #   Example:(LDAP_DEBUG_FILTER+LDAP_DEBUG_CONNS)
        ldap_debug = 0x0028
    }

    #
    #  This subsection configures the tls related items
    #  that control how FreeRADIUS connects to an LDAP
    #  server.  It contains all of the "tls_*" configuration
    #  entries used in older versions of FreeRADIUS.  Those
    #  configuration entries can still be used, but we recommend
    #  using these.
    #
    tls {
        # Set this to 'yes' to use TLS encrypted connections
        # to the LDAP database by using the StartTLS extended
        # operation.
        #
        # The StartTLS operation is supposed to be
        # used with normal ldap connections instead of
        # using ldaps (port 636) connections
        start_tls = no

#       ca_file = ${certdir}/cacert.pem

#       ca_path = ${certdir}
#       certificate_file = /path/to/radius.crt
#       private_key_file = /path/to/radius.key
#       random_file = ${certdir}/random

        #  Certificate Verification requirements.  Can be:
        #    "never" (don't even bother trying)
        #    "allow" (try, but don't fail if the certificate
        #       can't be verified)
        #    "demand" (fail if the certificate doesn't verify.)
        #
        #  The default is "allow"
#       require_cert    = "demand"
    }


    #  As of version 3.0, the "pool" section has replaced the
    #  following configuration items:
    #
    #  ldap_connections_number

    #  The connection pool is new for 3.0, and will be used in many
    #  modules, for all kinds of connection-related activity.
    #
    #  When the server is not threaded, the connection pool
    #  limits are ignored, and only one connection is used.
    pool {
        #  Number of connections to start
        start = 5

        #  Minimum number of connections to keep open
        min = 4

        #  Maximum number of connections
        #
        #  If these connections are all in use and a new one
        #  is requested, the request will NOT get a connection.
        #
        #  Setting 'max' to LESS than the number of threads means
        #  that some threads may starve, and you will see errors
        #  like "No connections available and at max connection limit"
        #
        #  Setting 'max' to MORE than the number of threads means
        #  that there are more connections than necessary.
        max = ${thread[pool].max_servers}

        #  Spare connections to be left idle
        #
        #  NOTE: Idle connections WILL be closed if "idle_timeout"
        #  is set.
        spare = 3

        #  Number of uses before the connection is closed
        #
        #  0 means "infinite"
        uses = 0

        #  The lifetime (in seconds) of the connection
        lifetime = 0

        #  Idle timeout (in seconds).  A connection which is
        #  unused for this length of time will be closed.
        idle_timeout = 60

        #  NOTE: All configuration settings are enforced.  If a
        #  connection is closed because of "idle_timeout",
        #  "uses", or "lifetime", then the total number of
        #  connections MAY fall below "min".  When that
        #  happens, it will open a new connection.  It will
        #  also log a WARNING message.
        #
        #  The solution is to either lower the "min" connections,
        #  or increase lifetime/idle_timeout.
    }
}
```

side note my user filter is a bit different as I used authentik LDAP outpost
and as per
https://goauthentik.io/docs/providers/ldap

the username is mapped to cn

Thank you for taking the time to read all of this by the way

Comment: Not a programming question. Questions about professional server and networking issues belong on [sf]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using EAP-PEAP, are the passwords being stored in your LDAP directory as either plaintext (not advisable in production) or NTLM hashes?

If they're being stored as SHA hashes for example, you'll run into an issue of no known good password as the supplicant will respond to the access-challenge from the NAS with an NTLM hash which freeradius won't be able to use to calculate the corresponding SHA hash it receives from the LDAP server after binding.

When you're using radtest, you're sending a plaintext password which freeradius can convert to the appropriate hash for comparison.

If you're not using PEAP and/or your passwords are stored in your directory as plaintext or NTLM hashes, you can disregard this.